Egotistical numbers
One of the four groups is encoded (the right part). Fill in the rest of the right parts using "+"/"-" and then tell me the answer to this puzzle (which is a single word.)

235711...= ?????? → 
1491625...= ??????? → ---+---
13579...= ???? → 
246810...= ????? →
 
    
TZLSEI

FCXL
REOSM


The answer is:

 SELFIES - given that the meaning of 'selfie' is a photograph one takes on oneself, this would fit with the 'egotistical' title, and furthermore the way it is derived (read on...).

To find this answer:

 ...first work out what each string of numbers represents:

 235711... is the first 5 prime numbers concatenated (2,3,5,7,11). PRIMES has the right number of letters to match the 6 question marks alongside.

 1491625... is the first 5 square numbers concatenated (1,4,9,16,25), giving us SQUARES (fulfilling the 7 question marks).

 13579... is the first 5 odd numbers concatenated (1,3,5,7,9), giving us ODDS (4 question marks).

 246810... is the first 5 even numbers concatenated (2,4,6,8,10), giving us EVENS (5 question marks).

What's with the +/- characters?

 Look at the one we know: SQUARES maps to ---+---. This has the same number of characters as there are letters in 'SQUARES', suggesting a 1-1 mapping between letters and +/- symbols.

 What's so special about the 'A' (the only letter corresponding to a '+' symbol) in 'SQUARES' then? Well, if we look at the positions of each letter in the English alphabet (i.e. use A1Z26) we find that S-Q-U-A-R-E-S corresponds to 19-17-21-1-18-5-19. The '1' from the 'A' is the only square number among these. So might this mean that we are supposed to pick out the letters in each word whose numeric A1Z26 values satisfy the property, in some kind of 'self-fulfilling' way?

Let's explore this...

 With the same mapping process, we get:

 P-R-I-M-E-S = 16-18-9-13-5-19 = ---+++ (since only 13, 5 and 19 are prime)
 O-D-D-S = 15-4-4-19 = +--+ (since only 15 and 19 are odd)
 E-V-E-N-S = 5-22-5-14-19 = -+-+- (since only 22 and 14 are even)

 To extract the final answer, note that the strings of letters at the bottom of the puzzle correspond in length to the lengths of 'PRIMES', 'ODDS' and 'EVENS' - so let's focus just on the letters in these strings that map to the '+' symbols we just identified:

 TZLSEI (---+++)
FCXL (+--+)
 REOSM (-+-+-)

 This yields the letters SEI, FL and ES, which when combined together and anagrammed spell out the thematic word SELFIES!


That's it, good job!

rot13(gur 3 tebhcf ng gur obggbz nyfb zngpu gur cbfvgvbaf bs CEVZRF, BQQF, naq RIRAF, jvgu n oynax yvar sbe jurer FDHNERF jbhyq unir orra)
